# Python: Why do I get an exception using super() but not with explicit super class name?

Tags: python, super

I am getting an exception when I try to access a base class's property using `super()`, but not when I use the base class name explicitly.  Here is the derived class:

```
from CPSA_TransactionLogOutSet import CPSA_TransactionLogOutSet

class CPSA_TransactionFailureSet(CPSA_TransactionLogOutSet):
    def __init__(self, connection, failedTransactionKey):
        super().__init__(connection)
        CPSA_TransactionLogOutSet.C_TRANS_TYP = "TRANS_FAIL"
        super().C_TRANS_TYP = "TRANS_FAIL"
        super().DefaultTableName = 'CPSA_TRANSACTION_LOG_IN'
        super()._keyFields.append('J_TRANS_SEQ')
```

but trying to create an instance raises an `AttributeError` exception:

```
AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'C_TRANS_TYP'
```

The base class consists of an `__init__()` method and a set of properties, only one of which is shown here:

```
class CPSA_TransactionLogOutSet(Recordset):
    def __init__(self, connection):
        super().__init__(connection)
        self.DefaultTableName = 'CPSA_TRANSACTION_LOG_OUT'

    @property
    def C_TRANS_TYP(self):
        return self.GetValue('C_TRANS_TYP')
    @C_TRANS_TYP.setter
    def C_TRANS_TYP(self, value):
        self.SetValue('C_TRANS_TYP', value)
```

Why can't I use `super()` to access the `C_TRANS_TYP` property?

Comment: What exception do you get? Show the full error and traceback.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: the error would be `AttributeError: 'super' object has no attribute 'C_TRANS_TYP'` raised by the `super().C_TRANS_TYP = "TRANS_FAIL"` line, because `super()` objects don't support `__set__` (or `__del__` for that matter).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need to use `super()` *at all* because there is no override on the current class. The descriptor will be bound to `self` without `super()`. The same applies to the other attributes on `self`:

```
def __init__(self, connection, failedTransactionKey):
    super().__init__(connection)
    self.C_TRANS_TYP = "TRANS_FAIL"
    self.DefaultTableName = 'CPSA_TRANSACTION_LOG_IN'
    self._keyFields.append('J_TRANS_SEQ')
```

`super()` is only needed to access descriptors that would not otherwise be reachable via `self`. The *normal* access path (via the instance) suffices here.

`super()` can't be used to bind data descriptors in an assignment or `del obj.attr` statement, because `super()` objects do not implement `__set__` or `__delete__`. In other words, using `super().attribute` works for *reading* the attribute only, never for writing or deleting.

Setting `CPSA_TransactionLogOutSet.C_TRANS_TYP` is also incorrect; that *replaces the descriptor object* on the class. By executing that line, you removed the descriptor from the class hierarchy altogether, so neither `self.C_TRANS_TYP` nor `super().C_TRANS_TYP` would trigger the `property` you  defined before.

Comment: Thank you.  There's a lot here that I don't understand, but I think you just explained why, when I tried to insert the data from the TransactionFailureSet into the database table, it compained that I was trying to write null values into non-nullable fields.